# Is there a way to convert a string into a function? (get code from an API)

Tags: json, lua

let's say that i have a simple local variable:

`local foo = 1`

when i do `print(foo)` will show `1`.

but is possible to something like

`local printingOne = 'print('1')'`

and then

`SomeCommandToConvert(printingOne)`

to show `1` too ?

this is a simple example, but in reality i wanna get functions from an API, so i will get those via json, which will be an string in the end.

if something like this is possible in another language let me know too...

Comment: Look at function `loadstring()` or `load()`

Comment: thanks dude, this save me alot... i was about to give up

Comment: reading the manual helps... no need to give up